# Save the state of UIImageView using restorationIdentifier in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, state-restoration

I read in the documentation that the `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *restorationIdentifier` is capable of preserving the state of an `UIImageView` properties such as position, angle, etc. I tried adding the methods

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}
```

to the view controller. I have set the restoration ID of the view controller as `@"myFirstViewController` in the IB.

I have added the following methods to the view controller as well.

```
-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
[coder encodeObject:_myImageView.image forKey:@"UnsavedImage"];
[super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}

-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
_myImageView.image = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"UnsavedImage"];
[super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}
```

Am i supposed to add the first two methods in the `appDelegate` or the view controller?
The UIImageView is not getting preserved. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

To make the state preservation and restoration work there are two steps that are always required:

- The App delegate must opt-in
- Each view controller or view to be
  preserved/restored must have a restoration identifier assigned.

You should also implement `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` and `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` for views and view controllers that require state to be saved and restored.

Add the following methods to the view controller of your `UIImageView`.

```
-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageView.image)
                 forKey:@"YourImageKey"];

    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}

-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"YourImageKey"]];

    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}
```

State preservation and restoration is an optional feature so you need to have the application delegate opt-in by implementing two methods:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Useful article about state preservation:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/05/21/state-preservation-and-restoration.html

Comment: You have the [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:] for encoding and vice versa. One way to keep people on their toes.